# Unhandled error message while accessing android phone Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

I'm using ubuntu 19.10 from the last 2 months and It was working fine until today. When I try to open my android phone after connecting through USB cable it pops up this error message:

```
"Unhandled error message: The name: 1.134 was not provided by any.service file"
```

Answer (score 87):

[Legend has it that](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1026884) you can solve this by simply `killall nautilus` and open it again.

I use Nautilus, so this solution worked for me.

Comment: Yes, `sudo killall nautilus`  It works fine.

Comment: Had same problem when mounting a GoPro under i3 manjaro with pcmanfm. Closing all pcmanfm instances solved it as well

Comment: Thanks! `killall Thunar` also works for Thunar respectively

Comment: The legend is true for [PCManFM](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM) too, `sudo killall pcmanfm` and now it works. OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: `nautilus -q` also does the job. It quits nautilus and then you can access the phone's directory.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today, did some research and ended up installing *gmtp* (sudo apt-get install gmtp) and rebooting ubuntu. It worked fine then. I don't actually know if it was gmtp or rebooting that fixed it, but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, Restarting my computer worked for me.

Comment: rebooting phone worked for me